# List of lists with incremented elements

Tags: python, list

I've made some generic example of my problem.

I have something like this:

```
n = 2

test = [[[0,0] for j in range(1)] for k in range(n)]

print(test)
```

And I get the following output:

```
[[[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]]
```

But what I want - as output - is something like that:

```
[[[0, 0]], [[0, 0],[0, 0]]]
```

And for n = 3, the output must be:

```
[[[0, 0]], [[0, 0],[0, 0]], [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by specifying the `start` argument of `range`:

```py
[[[0,0] for _ in range(k)] for k in range(1, n+1)]
```

Output (for `n=3`):

```py
[[[0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```